# $parent.inState not a function error with Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, undefined

I'm using a named template and binding a list of data to that.  The binding works great, but I get the error on $parent.inState() call.  Looking at the sample below:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'peopleScript', data: people }"> </div>

<script id="peopleScript" type="text/html">
    <ul data-bind="foreach: people">
        <li>
            Name: <span data-bind="text: name"> </span>
            State: <span data-bind="{ text: state, css: { outOfState: !$parent.inState($data) } }"> </span>

            <span data-bind="visible: ($parent.inState($data))">
                In State
            <span>

            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removePerson">Remove</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click: addPerson">Add</button>
</script>
```

it says `$parent.inState` is not a function.  I already tried `$parents` too, but to no avail.  I know the code to apply the bindings works; if I just have the template inline, it works great.  I also know everything else is setup OK and that it can access the method just fine.  So it's simply it can't find inState for some reason.

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are passing `data` as people, then you would want to `foreach` on `$data` (unless your structure is really `people.people`.

You could do:

```
<div>
  <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'peopleScript', foreach: people }"></ul>
</div>
```

and just have the `li` in the template or with your current structure, do your `foreach` on `$data`.

The issue with `inState` is that the `template` creates one scope, then the `foreach` binding creates another.  So, when you are inside, you would have to go up two scopes.  You could do this by using `$parents[1]` like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RNWML/ or if it really is at the top level, then using `$root` is the easiest choice like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/RNWML/2/

Comment: My structure really is people.people :-) it's something I was playing around.  $parents[1] did the trick, thanks a lot